# Samba 4.10 server config: using module "vfs_fruit" changes file creation mask for Mac clients, and I cannot control it

Tags: macos, ubuntu, permissions, samba, vfs

TLDR; With `vfs objects = catia fruit streams_xattr` in my `smb.conf`, files created on the shares using Macs do not inherit permissions and get extended ACLs.

### Background

I'm setting up a NAS with a Samba share for our office, which is a 50/50 macOs/Windows 10 shop. Everyone should have access to the shares using dedicated user accounts.

I wanted to leverage the latest enhancements in Samba 4 when it comes to performance with Macs, and TimeMachine support, so I enabled the modules `vfs objects = catia fruit streams_xattr`

### Problem

Permissions are not inherited, and masks are not respected with these `vfs objects` set. I've tried a number of combinations of `force create`and `create mask`s, and also (as in the example below) `inherit permissions`
Without the `vfs objects` modules set, permissions are as expected.

My `smb.conf` (relevant excerpt):

```
[global]

   server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
   server role = standalone server
   client signing = disabled
   unix password sync = yes
   vfs objects = catia fruit streams_xattr   
   fruit:aapl = yes
   map to guest = bad user
   spotlight = yes
   unix extensions = no
   browseable = yes
   read only = no
   inherit permissions = yes

[OurShare]
   path = /storage/OurShare
   valid users = @office
```

`OurShare` has `2770` permissions:

```
ls -al /storage/OurShare
drwxrws---  adminuser  office  4096 Oct 22 03:56
```

From a Windows machine, any new directory created in `OurShare` gets `drwxrws---`, as expected.
However a directory created from a Mac gets `drwxr-xr-x+`, so they are not writable by the group and *that is the main problem here*.

`$ getfacl` on such a directory tells me

```
# file: OurShare/testfile
# owner: someuser
# group: office
user::rwx
user:someuser:rwx                 #effective:r-x
group::rwx                        #effective:r-x
group:office:rwx                  #effective:r-x
mask::r-x
other::r-x
```

If I remove the modules `vfs objects = catia fruit streams_xattr` from `smb.conf`, then the permissions of files/folders created from Macs match that of those created from Windows - ie. there is no problem.

But without these modules I loose support for `fruit:time machine` for Mac backup purposes, and `fruit:aapl`, an extension which "enhances several deficiencies when connecting from Macs" ([man vfs fruit](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/vfs_fruit.8.html)).

This is an Ubuntu 19.04 system, with Samba v4.10.0

### My question

How can I retain these Mac optimizations in Samba, while still being able to control permissions of created files and folders from the server side?

Thanks for all advice! This is driving me nuts

Comment: I just found a question, which this makes this a possible duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/486919/creating-a-directory-in-samba-share-from-osx-client-always-has-acl-maskr-x. However the answer is not accepted. I'll verify when I get a chance and update here accordingly

Answer (score 14):

Turns out this was (already answered)[https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/486919/creating-a-directory-in-samba-share-from-osx-client-always-has-acl-maskr-x] in the Unix stackexchange.

Answer:
Setting the global option `fruit:nfs_aces = no` will prevent macOS clients from modifying the UNIX mode of directories using NFS ACEs. An Access Control Entry is part of the Access Control List (ACL). This option defaults to `yes` - see the [vfs_fruit manpage](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/vfs_fruit.8.html).

I can confirm that disabling this option results in permission inheritance working as expected with Mac clients, as they already are with Windows clients.

Happy to have figured it out!

Comment: THIS ANSWER. THIS IS THE ANSWER. Oh thank you spent like 20 minutes figuring this out.

Comment: Seriously, I had a comment in my smb.conf _for years_ along the lines of "acl_xattr is disabled as it breaks copying folders from macOS". I tried turning it back on to see if it was fixed a few days ago, only to discover that I couldn't set up Time Machine for a new MacBook. It would fail at step to create the sparsebundle. Setting `fruit:nfs_aces = no` fixed it. Now, I just have to remember why I wanted acl_xattr in the first place (probably something with zfs...)

Thank you!